# What is meant with translation-invariant product- measure here?

Tags: measure-theory

> > Consider $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$. What is meant by a tranlation-invariant product-measure on $X$?

On which $\sigma$-algebra? What does translation-invariant mean here?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the $\sigma$-algebra is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra for the product topology.  Translation refers to translation in the group $\mathbb Z^2$.

EDIT: A cylinder set is a set of the form
$A = \{x \in X: x_p \in A_p \ \text{for}\ p \in S\}$, where $S \subset \mathbb Z^2$ is finite, and each $A_p \subseteq \{0,1,2\}$.  These generate the $\sigma$-algebra.  There are constants
$c, \mu_0, \mu_1, \mu_2 \ge 0$ with $\mu_0 + \mu_1 + \mu_2 = 1$ such that for any cylinder set, 
$$\mu(A) = c \prod_{p \in S} \sum_{t \in A_p} \mu_t$$

Comment: How does the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra for the product topoloy look like? And what is meant by product measure here?

Comment: And can you please add an explanation for translation-invariant, too? :-)

Comment: Translation-invariant in this case says the $\mu_0, \mu_1, \mu_2$ are the same for every $p$.