# Why will a "clock" exist a.s.?

Tags: measure-theory

Consider $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$ and the following process: At the next time step 1 always becomes 2. 2 always becomes 0 and 0 becomes 1 if at least one of its 4 neighbours is 1, otherwise it remains 0. Let $y_n\in X$ denote the state of the process at time $n$. So $y_n(x)$ is the state of the position $x$ at time $n$.

> > We call a set of distince points $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n=x_0$ a *clock* if $x_{i+1}$ is a neighbour of $x_i$ and $y(x_i)=i\text{ mod }3$.

Now there is the following Lemma 1:

> > If $y_0$ contains a clock, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_{3n}$ exists.

Now there is a claim I do not understand, namely:

> > If $y_0$ has distribution $\mu$ where $\mu$ is a translation invariant product measure, then Lemma 1 implies that $y_{3n}$ has a limit a.s.

resp.

> > If $y_0$ has distribution $\mu$ where $\mu$ is a translation invariant product measure, then Lemma 1 implies that under $\mu$ a clock will exist a.s.

Do you understand that?

Why will a clock exist a.s. under $\mu$?

I simply do not understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously if all $\mathbb P(y(x) = 0) = 0$
there is a.s. no clock.  So  I suppose they mean to require $\mathbb P(y(x) =0)$, $\mathbb P(y(x) = 1)$ and $\mathbb P(y(x) = 2)$ all nonzero.  Let $X = \{x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}, x_n = x_0\}$ be a "potential clock", where each $x_{i+1}$ is a neighbour of $x_i$ and $n \equiv 0 \mod 3$.  There exist such things, e.g.
with $n=6$ (assuming "neighbour" means "nearest neighbour", $n$ must be even because $\mathbb Z^2$ is bipartite).  There is nonzero probability that 
$X$ is a clock. The same probability applies to any translate of $X$.  If we take an 
infinite collection of disjoint translates of $X$, then almost surely 
some of these will be clocks.

Comment: 1. How is the product measure defined here? 2. Why is there a.s. no clock if $P(y(x)=0)=0$? 3. Why is there a nonzero probability that $X$ is a clock?

Comment: And 4. What is a translate of $X$?

Comment: 1.  As I replied to your other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051909/what-is-meant-with-translation-invariant-product-measure-here
2.  Because a clock requires y(x_0) = 0.
3.  $P(y(x_i) = y_i, i = 0 \ldots n-1) = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} P(y(x_i) = y_i) > 0$.

Comment: 4.  To translate $X$ by $v \in \mathbb Z^2$, add $v$ to each of its members.

Comment: Ok. The only part I did not understand yet is: "If we take an infinite collection of disjoint translates of X, then a.s. some of these will be clocks.". How do you mean that?

Comment: And from what do I know that this collection resp. the clocks that it contains a.s. are within the start configuratio $ y_0$, what is necessary for then applying Lemma 1?

Comment: By "will be clocks" I mean "will be clocks in $y_0$".  Given infinitely many independent events, each with probability $p > 0$, almost surely infinitely many occur.

Comment: I am very sorry but I still do not understand why "then alomst surely some of these will be clocks in $y_0$". ;(

Comment: Can you please explain that very last part again? Maybe then I can understand it. Up to now it is not clear to me why considering the collection of infinitely many disjoint translates of X and why almost surely some of these translates are clocks in $y_0$. I hope I will understand because I really need to understand that. Thank you!

Comment: If you have a sequence $E_j$ of independent events, each with probability $\mathbb P(E_j) = p > 0$, then $\mathbb P(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j) = 1$.  Do you understand that?

Comment: With independent you here mean disjoint? But if they are dis joint I can compute the probability of their union as sum of the probabilities and the sum then is $/infty$ when having infinetely many summands p.

Comment: Ah, this Borel-Cantelli?

Comment: And: Why is the neasure for example of your X defined? I only know the measure for cylinder sets but your X is no cylinder set, or?

Comment: Could you pls tell me how you measure $X$? Is it a cylinder set? And why are the translates of $X$ independent of each other?

Comment: ``$X$ is a clock'' is the union of finitely many cylinder sets, just like any event that depends only on finitely many $y(x)$.  Events that depend on $y(x)$ for $x$ in disjoint sets are independent because it's a product measure.

Comment: Sorry I do not see why that is a union of finite many cylinder sets. ;(